# NTFS external disc restore trashed items

Tags: external-disk, trash, ntfs

I guess I deleted files on my external NTFS storage. I think I can see those files in hidden folder $RECYCLE.BIN on this drive.

1. is it possible that the MAC NTFS writing stuff I set up before - so I can write on NTFS drives - handle trash as Windows isntead of .Trash folder as mac normaly do?
2. if it is, is there any way how to restore those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested deleting a file on an NTFS volume under OS X and it placed it in `.Trashes` on that volume.  Anything in `$RECYCLE.BIN` is from files deleted under Windows.

By the way, I'm using [Tuxera NTFS for Mac](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) for write support under OS X.

Comment: here goes my maybe last hope to find out what the hell happened to my _new folder in movies directory :( Actually my last hope is reocery tool if its still somehow somewhere on the disc but I doubt it since I am sure I didnt delete it with terminal command and I dont think there is a way how to skip a trash on mac with finder.